# Failure to precompile assets when pushing rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm fairly new to rails and web development in general, so maybe I'm forgetting to do something simple, but I've been stuck on this problem for hours. I'm trying to push my rails app to Heroku, and I keep getting a message "Precompiling assets failed". Scrolling up through the console, the only place I really see errors is

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-06-09T16:33:23.020943 #736]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a3606aeafbcd156e85ce23a261b8ffd5/public/assets/logo-7f005e1459dfe2528e40b953dcc9b0d4.png
remote:        PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "speed_records" does not exist
remote:        LINE 1: SELECT "speed_records".* FROM "speed_records"
remote:        ^
remote:        : SELECT "speed_records".* FROM "speed_records"
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "speed_records" does not exist
remote:        LINE 1: SELECT "speed_records".* FROM "speed_records"
remote:        ^
remote:        : SELECT "speed_records".* FROM "speed_records"
remote:        (in /tmp/build_a3606aeafbcd156e85ce23a261b8ffd5/app/assets/javascripts/googlemaps.js.erb)
remote:        /tmp/build_a3606aeafbcd156e85ce23a261b8ffd5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec'
```

This is a small project that I'm working with others on, and we're all deploying to separate Heroku apps to test our own work as one of the APIs that we're using doesn't work when run on localhost:3000. Other than that, the site runs fine on localhost, but Heroku won't allow me to push to it without errors. Even when I delete everything that I have locally, and clone the master branch from scratch, which is already hosted and working fine on a different Heroku, I still get an error when I try to push it myself. I think part of the issue could be related to the fact that we use  the sqlite3 gem for development, but postgres for production, as Heroku requires. However I'm really new to working with databases so I have no idea if that is actually correct or if I'm forgetting to do anything.

Thanks in advance for any help, I've spent hours googling this issue and am completely stumped.

edit: found the solution after spending way too much time on it. The root of the problem seemed to be that I wasn't using "bundle exec" before all my attempted rake commands. From my understanding, this is necessary when the versions of gems you're using for a specific project don't match the versions you've installed system wide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run migrations. It looks like one of your `.js.erb` assets is loading some data from a database table that doesn't exist.

You can fix this by running `rake db:migrate` before you run `rake assets:precompile,` but you should be aware that your assets will *not* be dynamically recomputed once precompiled, and whatever data exists in the database at the point of precompilation is the data you'll be stuck using.

Comment: I tried that, still no luck. I can precompile locally without errors, but when I push to Heroku it automatically runs "rake assets:precompile" again right after "bundle install". It seems like if I could run "rake db:migrate" on the Heroku side before precompiling, that may fix it, but everything is done automatically when I push to Heroku

Comment: You probably shouldn't be building a dependency on your database in your assets. Assets are completely static, they really don't need to depend on a database for data storage.

Comment: I think we might have to do it that way for this project. One part of the project involves using the google maps API and placing markers on it based on data we have previously collected, so I believe it must depend on the database in this case. Even if the way we are doing it isn't the best practice, my main concern is getting it properly deployed to Heroku in the first place so that I can test what I write, which for some reason is working perfectly fine for all my teammates but not for me.

Comment: Then you should make the actual data available outside of the asset pipeline. You really cannot use the asset pipeline for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then why would it work completely fine for all my teammates? I don't want to make major changes to the code that works for everyone else and risk messing them up in order to fix a problem that only I am having.

Comment: @KyleAlbany Are you team mates deploying to Heroku?

Comment: yes, everyone is deploying to a separate Heroku app for testing as one of the APIs that we use can't be run on localhost, and they aren't having any issues. I even deleted every rails related file I could find and reinstalled from scratch, then pulled the master branch from github, and get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this with people who have it running successfully?

Comment: Yes I have, they all had suggestions for things that might be going wrong but none of the possible fixes worked, and we're collectively out of ideas.

Comment: I think I finally got it working, I believe it came down to the fact that I wasn't doing bundle exec before rake with all these attempted fixes. From what I just read, using bundle exec guarantees that the command is run correctly in relation to the gems/versions you specify in your gemfile, while without it rake will run according to system wide preferences. This project uses rails 4.1.4 and some specific versions of other gems, while I have 4.2.1 installed system wide, which is what rake would default to.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced this type of issue.

```
Open config/environments/production.rb and make sure the following option is set to true:
```

then please run

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Did you mean set the config.assets.precompile to true? That is located in the assets.rb file (there's a comment in production.rb that it was moved, so maybe its part of a newer rails version). Either way, no luck with that method either.

Comment: Well I played around with what you said a little more, and the code finally pushed, but now I'm getting an application error with Heroku, and the logs are showing that the app keeps crashing. Not sure if this is a completely different problem but it seems to have made some progress

Comment: could you please tell me, which type of errors occurs

Comment: 2015-06-09T18:26:22.896336+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-06-09T18:26:22.896339+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-06-09T18:26:22.896343+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-06-09T18:26:23.825050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-09T18:26:23.811490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Comment: was too long for one comment, 2015-06-09T18:26:25.067587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fierce-plains-6253.herokuapp.com request_id=6362df4b-b0d5-4299-8f4b-d2d388518910 fwd="66.152.124.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: $ heroku rake db:setup or $ heroku rake db:push ...is needed?

Comment: Can't really format the error message correctly in comments. I'm not entirely sure what is going on in the logs, but after it tries to run something it says state changed from starting to crash, then process exited with status 1, then erro code=H10 desc="App crashed" keeps repeating

Comment: When I run rake db:setup it tells me permission denied for database "postgres"

Comment: are you set postgres username and pasword

Comment: heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL, then
 
heroku rake db:migrate

Comment: seems like there were no problems running those commands, but still constantly crashing

Comment: I'm at a complete loss right now, I think I'm going to just setup my entire rails environment from scratch again and then pull from github. I appreciate the help though